# Placement of “normally” in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Is this grammatically correct:
“He normally doesn’t do this.” or do I have to write :
“He doesn’t normally do this”
If the first is not grammatically correct, why not?

Comment: The latter sounds more natural. Besides [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) doesn't return any results for *normally \* n't do*.

Comment: Isn't it an option too? Normally, he doesn't do it.

Comment: The only unacceptable place to put _normally_ here is immediately after _do_. [These Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=doesn%27t+normally%2Cnormally+doesn%27t&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdoes%20not%20normally%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnormally%20does%20not%3B%2Cc0) show that both are used, 'doesn't normally' being twice as commonly chosen.